# ffmpeg how to convert mkv vp90 to mp4 h.264?

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, video-conversion

i would like to ask how to convert an .mkv VP90 to an mp4 h.264 ?

I downloaded .mkv video from youtube and it's using VP90, VLC is unable to read VP90, so i have to convert it to my usual H.264, in .mp4 container, but i don't know how to proceed. As for the audio codec, in the mkv file it is (undf) codec, i never heard of (undf) so i would like to also convert the audio to .AAC 44100Hz.

Thanks

Comment: I think this question belongs on the [ffmpeg forum](https://www.ffmpeg.org/contact.html), no?

Comment: I'm pretty sure ffmpeg is the tool for your needs. Also *undf* means *undefined*  or unknown.

Comment: Please show the complete console output of: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr).  It's easy to use and has a high chance of supporting the file you want to convert.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg doesn't have a stable built-in AAC encoder, so this command will just copy the audio stream in the same format to the output file. If VLC still doesn't like the audio codec, you can change the `copy` in `-c:a copy` to some other [codec listed here.](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#toc-Audio-Encoders)

```
ffmpeg -i <input file> -c:a copy -c:v libx264 <output file>
```

FFmpeg should automatically detect the input file container and codecs, and should automatically determine the output file container based off of the extension. You might also benefit from looking at the [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) to learn how to create these commands yourself.

Comment: FFmpeg has a native AAC encoder (`-c:a aac`). It is currently marked as "experimental" (thus it requires `-strict experimental`) but there are several improvements pending. Although it is "experimental" it is considered to be better than at least one, non-experimental supported external AAC encoder: `libvo_aacenc`.